# Hibernate - Join tables using value that return function

Tags: oracle, hibernate, function, join

Is it possible to join tables using not value of column, and value that return oracle function?
Something like this:

```
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "columnName", name = "PackageName.functionName(param)")
```

Comment: Would something like the @Where annotation help you?

Comment: No, because hibernate think that it additional condition, and add primary key and foreign key by default. But I want to have only one condition somethink like this: where function(columnFromFistTable) = columnFromSecondTable